# error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Tags: openssl

I am using openssl to sign certificate in CentOS 7.4 like this:

```
[root@ops001 cert]# openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ./kubernetes.crt -CAkey kubernetes-key.pem -days 3650 -CAcreateserial -out client.crt
```

but it shows this error:

```
Signature ok
subject=/CN=dolphin/O=dabai
unable to load certificate
139673019578256:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I did not know where is going wrong, what should I do to fix this problem?

```
[root@ops001 cert]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution ?

Comment: sorry,I forget how to solve this problem because I focus to solve problem.you can try another version of openssl. @khalidmehmoodawan